# hover on table to change another element style with jquery, works for only 1 mil second

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want a text to be underlined when hovering any area of a certain table.

Here's my code, it works but only for 1 mil second and then the underline fades away even though the cursor is inside the table (tried both `go` and `foo` to test):

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('.foo').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".vvv").addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".vvv").removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
})
</script>
```

CSS:

```
.altbg {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="go">
<table border="1" class="foo">
        <col style="width:115px;" />
        <col style="width:280px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:145px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:230px;" />
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr></table>
</div>
<div class="vvv">Hello</div>
```

**EDIT: Second related question:**

I want the text color to change when hovering the table, even though the color is already defined by ID.

besides changing the ID to class, How can I make this div change it's color?

Maybe something in the script needs to be change in order to specify the class to the selector, but I don't know how to do it.

JS:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('td').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".vvv").addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".vvv").removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
})
</script>
```

CSS:

```
#meh {color:red}

.altbg {
    text-decoration:underline;
    color:blue;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="go">
<table border="1" class="foo">
        <col style="width:115px;" />
        <col style="width:280px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:145px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:230px;" />
          <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
          </tr></table>
</div>
<div id="meh" class="vvv">Hello</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the time of the hover, but the location of the mouse that makes it not appear for longer. For some reason targeting the `table`'s class will not work, instead you have to target the `td` element inside of it:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        $('td').mouseenter(function () {
            $(".vvv").addClass('altbg')
        }).mouseout(function () {
            $(".vvv").removeClass('altbg')
        });
    });
})
```

```css
.altbg {
    text-decoration:underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="go">
    <table border="1" class="foo">
        <col style="width:115px;" />
        <col style="width:280px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:145px;" />
        <col style="width:125px;" />
        <col style="width:230px;" />
        <tr>
            <td>0</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
<div class="vvv">Hello</div>
```

Here is a jsfiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/0uqboeat/ too.

Comment: Out of curiosity, What's the point in posting a jsfiddle while you've already shared a snippet? o.0

Comment: @TJ dunno, just got used to it, i didn't use SO's snippets before... ;)

Comment: @webeno thanks, perhaps you can also solve my related question? i've edited this one since I can't post another for the next hour.

Comment: @TJ just realized the reason I added the jsfiddle link: with the SO snippet, one can only run it, cannot edit or play with it (at least if you're not the answerer or have sufficient points to edit the post), while you can do all that in jsfiddle...

Answer (score 1):

It works the only issue is that you need (td) instead of (foo). So (td) is the table cell.

**Demo**

http://jsfiddle.net/u0dz0xtu/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(function(){
    $('td').mouseenter(function(){
        $(".vvv").addClass('altbg')
    }).mouseout(function(){
        $(".vvv").removeClass('altbg')
    });
});
})
```